# python module speech_recognition recognized only first 5 seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, wav, speech-to-text

guys, i have a problem with speech recognition on python3.x
I using module speech_recognition.
My .wav file have length 5 minutes, however python recognized only first 5 seconds of this file.
I have never worked with this module.
Please, help me

My code

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\Unlocking.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
text = r.recognize_google(audio)
print(text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Speech Recognition duration setting issue in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59020670/speech-recognition-duration-setting-issue-in-python)

Comment: No,  i put timeout, but program works without changes

Comment: It doesn't seem this module is used long time like minutes order. Some solutions are here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097204/how-to-increase-listen-time-in-google-speech-api

Comment: It is better to use google streaming python api directly without this wrapper